# Extract text from journalctl logging facility

Tags: linux, logging, systemd, raspbian

I have a system which I can access directly with the keyboard [but not by `ssh`](https://superuser.com/questions/1091051/cant-login-with-putty-to-raspi-3-osmc) (which is my problem, and which arises the question; a RasPi 3 with OSMC 2016.05-1, which is Debian-based, version: 8.5). I raised the logging level for the `ssh` demon to `DEBUG` and got two screens full of lines in the `journalctl`.

There must be a way to extract those `sshd` lines; otherwise I'd need to copy it manually, or to take photos with my camera ... Perhaps I can get the result by `ftp`.

So, how can I extract the interesting lines (and have hope to get help for my `ssh` problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `netcat` to be able to paste to sites like [termbin](http://www.termbin.com/):

```
# apt-get install netcat-traditional
```

And then pipe the `sshd` logs to termbin.com:

```
# journalctl -u sshd --no-pager | nc termbin.com 9999
```

You will get a link containing your sshd logs.

Comment: This worked nicely, thank you! `nc` was present already. I had problems with the `|` and `\\ ` keys (oh my), so I needed to create a litte shellscript, and get the pipe character with Python's `chr` function (`chr(124)`) ...

Comment: For the records, `journalctl -u sshd` didn't give me the desired output (from looking at the help, it should have done so; a bug in the OSMC version?). So I created an unfiltered text file first, and then handcrafted an excerpt myself which I then sent to termbin.com.